# After updating to Magento CE 1.9.1 main navigation sub menus don't show

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade

I updated from 1.9 to 1.9.1. 
Since then if I hover of any category menu, the sub-menus don't show any more.

Does Magento 1.9 main navigation works with jQuery or any other js library?
Could it be a jQuery conflict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all there is a 404 error which can be seen in dev tools console, error says:

```
http://happygemslondon.co.uk/skin/frontend/base/default/js/lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

which means that the jquery file provided by the latest version was not found on your server. You should check if you haven't forgot about any files during the upgrade, eventually you should upload missing file to the base/default (or your custom) namespace.